# Is it possible to create a market place style app with paypal?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on a web application for a client and he wants the payflow to work sorta like this:

```
Seller makes an offer for an item
Customer purchases the item
The seller sees the item is paid for but won't get the payment
When the item has been marked shipped the payment minus app fee and paypal fees will be sent to seller
App Fee is deposited into the application's paypal account
```

I have implemented it using paypal's express payment api and do the payouts manually. But this has caused double paypal fee's which are incorrect. My client wants to use adaptive payments but that isn't going to work since they require the seller to be the primary receiver and the merchant service be the secondary but for out desired flow that won't work. What other option do I have?

Answer (score 0):

From the description you provide, the best approach is to use Adaptive Payment Delayed Chained Payment. The buyer will make a payment for the item and the seller will directly receive the amount. You can specify the merchant services to be the secondary receiver but when using the Delayed Chained Payment, primary receiver (seller) will always get the payment first and using the Pay API, secondary receiver (merchant services) will get their portion. If you required the seller to be the last person to receive the money then they (seller) should be the secondary receiver.

Comment: That's what my client and I was planning where the seller would be the secondary. But PayPal is saying that the merchant cannot be the primary receiver.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?