# PayPal AppId Rejected Due to Aggregation

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, marketplace

I run a website that connects between 2 types of users (those providing a service & those receiving said service).
I wish to facilitate payment between these 2 parties.

My original plan was to use PayPal's Delayed Chained Payments (take payment from service-receiver at start of work and pay (via delayed chain) service-provider at end of work).
However, when I applied for an AppId with PayPal and described my scenario, they denied my application stating that the reason for the denial is "aggregation".

PayPal was very brief in their explanation of why I was denied and surprisingly have not responded yet to my requests for more detail.

1) Is there anything I can do to keep my current payment flow (using Delayed Chained Payments) and have PayPal approve my AppId? For example, if they have an issue with trusting me perhaps it will help if I incorporated my business (which I have not done yet).

2) Are there any other payment structures (I am located outside of the U.S. and Europe) I can use to achieve what I want to achieve and be approved? 
I have considered using "Preapprovals" instead of Delayed Chained Payment. This will not be considered aggregation but it is also a lot riskier for me as the payment facilitator because I will not be guaranteed that the money is in my possession until after the work is carried out.

I realize some of these question might be better suited to PayPal but I have had trouble getting them to respond (at least within the last few days).

Thank you

Comment: Have you submitted any ticket to PayPal MTS? If not, please file one because this rejection of App ID is something related to their policy.

Comment: I have, response has been slow as of yet...Yes, I've seen aggregation explained in the policies. However, I've also seen posts stating that they used AP to execute the payment structure that I have outlined

Comment: Can you DM me the ticket number?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, they have responded. It was taking longer than usual and I got frustrated. My question above is still relevant though. (I'm not aware of any DM function). Thanks.

Comment: I actually see that you have supported this payment structure in a previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191382/is-it-possible-to-create-a-market-place-style-app-with-paypal). How do you recommend I get it approved in my application?